# Preserve Original Parameter Value between Recursive Calls (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, function, recursion

Observe the following Python 2.7 function:

```
def replace(c, st):
  if st == "":
    return []
  else:
    temp = [st + c]
    c += c
    return temp + replace(c, st[:-1])

print replace("z", "Howdy")
```

And observe the output:

```
['Howdyz', 'Howdzz', 'Howzzzz', 'Hozzzzzzzz', 'Hzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz']
```

Notice how the number of z's doubles each time.  That makes sense considering that, between recursive calls, the modified version gets added to itself after each call and then passed as a parameter.  But suppose the desired output is this:

```
['Howdyz', 'Howdzz', 'Howzzz', 'Hozzzz', 'Hzzzzz']
```

Notice that this would be equivalent to:

```
def replace(c, st):
  if st == "":
    return []
  else:
    temp = [st + c]
    c += INITIAL_VALUE_OF_C
    return temp + replace(c, st[:-1])

print replace("z", "Howdy")
```

So the goal here would be to somehow store the initial value of c without it being changed between recursive calls.  I can think of several solutions to this problem, but none of them seem very elegant.  For example, this function could be the method of a class which stores the initial value as a member variable, but then the class has to be instantiated with a constructor in order to use the function.  I could also add another parameter to the function, one which is a duplicate of "c", but remains unchanged between function calls.  However, this forces the function to have another parameter, which isn't ideal.  **So the goal here is to find an elegant way to preserve the initial value of a parameter between recursive function calls, specifically when that parameter changes after each call.  How would you do this?**

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution if `c` is always exactly one character, just replace this line:

```
c += c
```

with this:

```
c += c[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is replace `c+=c` with `c += c[0]` since you just want to increase c's occurrence by one.